# Google Oauth and Sencha touch

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch, google-oauth

I am developing an application in Sencha touch and packaging it using cordova.

Can we use `access_type='offline'/'online'` as parameter when we are using OAuth 2.0 for devices while requesting through AJAX.

I am developing it in JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

Generally the answer is no. Refresh Tokens are intended to be stored securely on a server, rather than downloaded to a browser. Having said that, with JavaScript being used more and more to create local apps, there is a grey zone and there may well be use cases where this makes sense.

The other alternative is simply to do repeated gapi.auth.authorize() with immediate=true